# Jquery textarea autogrow not working when adding items programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've tried 
http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin-version-2-0/
and
https://gist.github.com/802204#file_live_sample.js

TextArea's autogrow, and they work great if you add items with the keyboard, but if you add items programmatically (say 1 new item each second) they do not autogrow.

Anyone know how or where I can find an autogro textarea that will autogrow if I add new items programmatically? 
(for example with $('#txtUDSMessagesNotHandled').val($('#textarea').val()+'new text + '\n');

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `live-sample.js`, we see this:

```
$('.js-auto-grow').live('keyup keydown change', function(evt) {
```

So the plugin is binding to three events. The one you care about is `change`. The thing is, when you say `$('#x').val('pancakes')`, the `change` event is not triggered. Play around with this:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FPB4q/1/

and you'll see. Or, from the [fine manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> **change**
>   The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

When you simply call `$x.val('pancakes')`, there is no focus change happening so no `change` event is triggered.

All you need to do is trigger the event yourself:

```
$('#txtUDSMessagesNotHandled')
    .val($('#textarea').val()+'new text + '\n')
    .change();
```

and then it should work fine.

Also note that the plugin requires that the `<textarea>` have both `row` and `column` attributes or it won't work. Here's a demo of it working:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Sr5gm/

Comment: Hi Mu,
     I've tried it but it still doesn't work, elements are added and hide when there are more than the textarea can hold on screen. Scrollbars are not added either when the max is reached is that's helpfull.

Comment: @polonskyg: Can you set it up on jsfiddle.net so that I can see what you're doing?

Comment: I think you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/FPB4q/3/. I don't know how to use it properly, but I just entered this:
$('#x').autoGrow();
$('#x').change(function() {
    alert('changed');
});
$('#a').click(function() {
    $('#x').val($('#x').val() + 'pancakes');
});
$('#b').click(function() {
    $('#x').val($('#x').val() + 'pancakes').change();
});
And added a reference to https://gist.github.com/802204.js

Comment: @polonskyg: Couple things. I fixed up the plugin resource in that fiddle (you need to use the "raw" option on the gist to get the right URL). And it looks like the plugin requires `row` and `column` attributes on the `<textarea>`. I added a fully functional fiddle to my answer.